# Fastest way to copy a large MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, copy

What's the best way to copy a large MySQL table in terms of **speed** and **memory** use?

**Option 1.** Using PHP, select X rows from old table and insert them into the new table. Proceed to next iteration of select/insert until all entries are copied over.

**Option 2.** Use MySQL `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` without row limits.

**Option 3.** Use MySQL `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` with a limited number of rows copied over per run.

**EDIT:** I am not going to use mysqldump. The purpose of my question is to find the best way to write a database conversion program. Some tables have changed, some have not. I need to automate the entire copy over / conversion procedure without worrying about manually dumping any tables. So it would be helpful if you could answer which of the above options is best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the three options listed above.

I would select the second option **if** you have a Unique constraint on at least one column, therefore not creating duplicate rows if the script has to be run multiple times to achieve its task in the event of server timeouts.

Otherwise your third option would be the way to go, while manually taking into account any server timeouts to determine your insert select limits.

Comment: Please elaborate, why does this require a unique constraint? How would it create duplicate rows if I all I am doing is issue one INSERT ... SELECT query?

Comment: I just edited my answer to detail it a bit. I had to move a sql db to a mysql format recently. I output each row in the SQL table as an insert query in a file, then used php to loop through the file and insert into the mysql table, this table had 1 million plus rows and required multiple times to be ran for all the rows to be inserted in the destination table. I found that tables with Unique constraints I could just run the file multiple times until all rows were added. In the event the table did not have a constraint every time the file ran it would insert rows from the beginning(naturally).

Answer (score 11):

There is a program that was written specifically for this task called [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html).

Comment: Yeah in linux terminal: mysqldump -uUSER_NAME -p DB_NAME > /the/path/to/save/test.sql . This creates a dump of your db in a sql file and then when you restore create a empty db and in linux terminal : mysql -uUSER_NAME -p DB_NAME < /the/path/to/save/test.sql

Answer (score 9):

mysqldump is a great tool in terms of simplicity and careful handling of all types of data, but it is not as fast as *load data infile*

If you're copying on the same database, I like this version of Option 2:

a) CREATE TABLE foo_new LIKE foo;

b) INSERT INTO foo_new SELECT * FROM foo;

I've got lots of tables with hundreds of millions of rows (like 1/2B) AND InnoDB AND several keys AND constraints.  They take many many hours to read from a MySQL dump, but only an hour or so by *load data infile*.  It is correct that copying the raw files with the DB offline is even faster.  It is also correct that non-ASCII characters, binary data, and NULLs need to be handled carefully in CSV (or tab-delimited files), but fortunately, I've pretty much got numbers and text :-).  I might take the time to see how long the above steps a) and b) take, but I think they are slower than the *load data infile*... which is probably because of transactions.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, the fastest way will be to take the database offline and simply copy data files on disk.

Of course, this have some requirements:

- you can stop the database while copying.
- you are using a storage engine that stores each table in individual files, MyISAM does this.
- you have privileged access to the database server (root login or similar)

Ah, I see you have edited your post, then I think this DBA-from-hell approach is not an option... but still, it's fast!

Comment: I am not interested in copying over the whole database. See my post above.

Comment: copying datafiles is not guaranteed to be problem free, even if the database is down.

Comment: Nope, it's not problem free, it requires you know what you are doing and data dependencies. But then.. it's fast!

Comment: You can copy a single database table, not the whole thing, using this method. And actually you can do it while mysql is running. All you have to do is lock the table, flush it, then copy the files (TABLE.frm, TABLE.MYI, and TABLE.MYD) to new files using a consistent naming scheme (NEW_TABLE.frm, NEW_TABLE.MYI, and NEW_TABLE.MYD).

Answer (score 1):

**Use a stored procedure**

Option two must be fastest, but it's gonna be a mighty long transaction. You should look into making a stored procedure doing the copy. That way you could offload some of the data parsing/handling from the MySQL engine.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL's `load data` query is faster than almost anything else, however it requires exporting each table to a CSV file.

Pay particular attention to escape characters and representing `NULL` values/binary data/etc in the CSV to avoid data loss.

Answer (score 0):

The best way i find so far is creating the files as dump files(.txt), by using the outfile to a text then using infile in mysql to get the same data to the database

Answer (score 0):

Here a little benchmark:

Tested table backup of more than  **26 millions** records and **10 columns** with MySql:

- `mysqldump -u user -p database table > /path/to/file/backup.sql`: 30 secs.
- `CREATE TABLE backup LIKE table;` +
  `INSERT INTO backup (SELECT * FROM table);` : 5 mins
- `CREATE TABLE backup AS (SELECT * FROM table);` : 5 mins